# Puppeteer no hace request en produccion al mismo server que tiene el puppeteer instalado pero si a API externa

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, ubuntu-server, puppeteer

Tengo un server con Ubuntu 22.04 en el cual estoy implementando puppeteer para generar recibos en pdf, todo funciona bien en local pero al subir cambios al servidor la peticion que optiene los datos para el recibo nunca se ejecuta.
El endpoint que optiene estos datos está en el mismo servidor que hace el page.goto de puppeteer.
Basicamente mi flujo es.

- Se da click en descargar recibo en el front.
- El back saca los parametros que necesita la vista del front para optener la info del pago.
- Se genera una url con estos parametros para visitar el front.
- Hago el `page.goto(${host-front}/pdf-generator-receipt/payment?data={"orderId":${orderId},"businessId":${businessId},"paymentId":${paymentId}})`
- El front saca los parametros de la url.
- Se hace la peticion usando Axios. *<- aqui falla. La peticion nunca llega al server.*
- El back responde con un JSON.
- La info del JSON se pone en el recibo de pago.
- Puppeteer espera a que la imagen del pdf se muestre.
- Se convierte la pagina a un pdf y se descarga.

DownloadReportController:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    args: [
      "--disable-web-security",
    ],
    defaultViewport: {
      width: 750,
      height: 500,
      deviceScaleFactor: 1,
      isMobile: false,
      hasTouch: false,
      isLandscape: false,
    }
  });
  const token = req?.headers?.authorization;
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setExtraHTTPHeaders({
    'Authorization': token
  });

  await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle0'}, { timeout: 60000 });
  logger.info('Puppeteer esta visitando la url: ' + url);
  await page.waitForSelector('#logo');
  await page.emulateMediaType('screen');

  const pdfOptions = {
    format: 'A4',
    printBackground: true,
    margin: { left: "0cm", top: "1cm", right: "0cm", bottom: "4cm" },
    displayHeaderFooter: true,
    footerTemplate: footerPdf,
    headerTemplate: headerPdf,
  };

  const pdf = await page.pdf(pdfOptions);
  await browser.close();
```

Action:

```
export const fetchPaymentstoPDF = (data) => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      dispatch(fetchDummyApi());
      const { orderId, businessId, paymentId } = data;
      let stringDataSearch = '';
      stringDataSearch += `${businessId}`;
      stringDataSearch += `/orderId/${orderId}`;
      stringDataSearch += `/paymentId/${paymentId}`;
      const request = await requestHandler({
        method: 'GET',
        path: `/payment/get-payments-business/${stringDataSearch}`,
      });
      dispatch(fetchPaymentstoPDFSuccess(request));
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('ERROR IN FETCH PAYMENTS => ', error);
      dispatch(fetchPaymentstoPDFError(error));
    }
  };
};
```

Controllador de get-payments-business

```
  async buildPaymentInfo(req, res) {
    const { orderId, paymentId } = req.params;
    logger.info( `${orderId} - buildPaymentInfo.req.params - ${paymentId}`);


    let businessId =
      req.user.roleId === 3 || req.user.roleId === 25
        ? req.params.businessId
          ? req.params.businessId
          : req.user.businessId
        : req.user.businessId
          ? req.user.businessId
          : req.params.businessId;
    try {

      const response = await builderPaymentBuilder.builderPaymentInformacion({
        orderId,
        businessId,
        paymentId,
      });
      logger.info( `buildPaymentInfo`, response);

      const result = {
        message: 'OK',
        outPut: response,
      }

      return handleResponse.success(result, res);
    } catch (error) {
      return handleResponse.error(error, res);
    }

  }
```

Comment: "Falla", ¿te da algún error? ¿Cuál?. Una falla puede ser cualquier cosa. Trata de ser más específico. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour], también puedes leer [mre]. No podemos adivinar tu código sólo por la descripción que haces.

Comment: Solo no llega la petición al server de back, agregue unos loggers y vi que la peticion no llega, pero una peticion a un endpoint dummy como por ejemplo https://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees si optiene los datos.
Deje partes de mi codigo, pero me parece por lo que he obserbado que va a ser tema de configuracion de mi server de back

Answer (score 0):

Logré resolverlo cambiando la url de la peticion por localhost, dado que el chromium de puppeteer esta en el mismo server que el endpoint get-payments-business**texto en negrita**.

```
const request = await requestHandler({
    method: 'GET',
    baseUrl: `http://localhost:8000/api/payment/get-payments-business/${stringDataSearch}`,
  });
```